# Does UI-Grid supports angular 4? if yes what are the basic integration steps

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Does **UI-Grid** supports angular 4 ? 
if yes what are the basic integration steps.

Answer (score 1):

I feel UI grid currently doesn't support angular 4; angular 2 is supported. please get help here https://gitter.im/angular/angular?source=orgpage